# Difficulties on mapping many-to-many relation with extra column with hibernate XML mapping

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am developing a e-shopping program with the help of hibernate. Because I am a very fresh beginner on jsp, servlet, hibernate, I don't know how to do many-to-many relation mapping with additional column in the relation table. I have read through several tutorial but most of them are focus on the annotation mapping and the documentation on hibernate community but none of them suit my situation.

I have three tables `movie_information`, `order_` and `order_details`(the relationship) where the structure of `order_details` is as the following.

```
order_details
-------------
order_id FK
movie_id FK
quantity
-------------
```

I am trying to use four POJO classes to achieve the many-to-many relation. Here comes the code.

MovieInformation.java

```
// other variable, constructor, getter, setter
private Set<OrderDetails> orderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetails>();
```

Order.java

```
// other variable, constructor, getter, setter
private Set<OrderDetails> orderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetails>();
```

OrderDetails.java

```
private OrderDetailsPK primaryKey;
private Order order;
private MovieInformation movie;
private int quantity;
```

OrderDetailsPK.java

```
private long orderId;
private long movieId;
```

MovieInformation.hbm.xml

```
<id column="movie_id" name="movieId" type="long">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>

 // some property

<set name="orderDetails" table="order_details" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key>
        <column name="movie_id" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="cart.hibernate.orderDetails.orderDetails" />
</set>
```

Order.hbm.xml

```
<id column="order_id" name="orderId" type="long">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>

//some properties

<set name="orderDetails" table="order_details" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key>
        <column name="order_id" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="cart.hibernate.orderDetails.orderDetails" />
</set>
```

OrderDetails.hbm.xml

```
<composite-id name="orderDetailsPK" class="cart.hibernate.orderDetailsPK.OrderDetailsPK">
  <key-property column="order_id" name="orderId" type="long"/>
  <key-property column="movie_id" name="movieId" type="long"/>
</composite-id>

<many-to-one name="order" class="cart.hibernate.order.Order" insert="false" update="false"/>
<many-to-one name="movie" class="cart.hibernate.movieInformation.MovieInformation" insert="false" update="false"/>
<property column="quantity" name="quantity" type="int"/>
```

OrderDetailsPK.hbm.xml

```
<class name="cart.hibernate.orderDetailsPK.OrderDetailsPK" >
  <property  name="orderId" type="long"/>
<property name="movieId" type="long"/>
```

hibernate.cfg.cml

```
<mapping class="cart.hibernate.MovieInformation" package="cart.hibernate.movieInformation" resource="cart/hibernate/movieInformation/MovieInformation.hbm.xml"/>        
<mapping class="cart.hibernate.Order" package="cart.hibernate.order" resource="cart/hibernate/order/Order.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping class="cart.hibernate.OrderDetails" package="cart.hibernate.orderDetails" resource="cart/hibernate/orderDetails/OrderDetails.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping class="cart.hibernate.OrderDetailsPK" package="cart.hibernate.orderDetailsPK" resource="cart.hibernate.orderDetailsPK/OrderDetailsPK.hbm.xml"/>
```

When I try to run the testing main method, exception thrown from the program

```
887 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : 
cart.hibernate.orderDetailsPK/OrderDetailsPK.hbm.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: cart.hibernate.orderDetailsPK/OrderDetailsPK.hbm.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cart.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:28)
    at cart.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    at cart.hibernate.order.ManageOrder.main(ManageOrder.java:40)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: cart.hibernate.orderDetailsPK/OrderDetailsPK.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2344)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2310)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2290)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2243)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at cart.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:23)
    ... 2 more
```

After I read through the question ask by the others, I believe that the error in my code is caused by wrong mapping code. Hope you guys could help me to solve this problem. It would be nice if some simple examples of many-to-many mapping with extra column are provided.

Comment: Do you use an inner class for `OrderDetailsPK`?

Comment: No, it's a separate class. Should I use inner class?

Comment: Just a comment: it will be harder and harder to find people helping you with Hibernate XML files, because these were the way you configured Hibernate years ago, when Java was at version 4 and annotations didn't exist. The world has moved on, and we're now almost at Java 8, and the standard way is to use annotations. You'd better do yourself a favor and learn to use them. Not only will you do things the standard way, but also the easier way.

Comment: Ok, thx for your kind reminder, I will use annotation in my next project. It is the very first time I use hibernate and jsp so I do not know much about on the concept of hibernate. That's why I just randomly choose to use xml when I begin my project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your code is clean because the console told you `MappingNotFoundException` Once it loaded the hibernate file, it couldn't find it.  Make sure that the hibernate file in the package of the model bean is not in the source.